# MATLAB® export double numbers into PostgreSQL by `datainsert` (of Database Toolbox)

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, postgresql-9.4, export

How is it possible to pass **double numers into numeric** postgreSQL **columns** from MATLAB?

Here the list of matlab data:

```
var1    197x1 cell
var2    197x1 double
var3    197x2 double
var4    197x2 double
var5    197x2 double
```

Here the list of postgreSQL columns:

```
col1        text    NOT NULL ,
col2        numeric(10,4),
col3        numeric(20,4),
col4        numeric(30,20),
col5        numeric(30,20),
col6        numeric(20,4),
col7        numeric(30,20),
col8        numeric(30,20),
```

Here the code (from script.m) I used:

```
for r=[1:n]
    colnames={'col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6','col7','col8'};
    data={char(var1(r)),var2(r,1),var3(r,1),var4(r,1),var5(r,1),var6(r,2),var7(r,2),var8(r,2)};
    datainsert(conn,tablename,colnames,data);
end
```

This code passes only numbers before the comma.

Comment: You figured out it in your earlier question - import to `double precision` and then cast it to `numeric` inside PostgreSQL.

Comment: Alter  already created columns type into double and then  reconvert all of them requires lot of time, maybe there is a way to insert properly double type into numeric cell from matlab and maybe someone knows it. My research has arrived to the solution you suggest, but I wonder if there is a faster way to do it acting in matlab. Thank you anyway @dezso

Comment: I think the casting in PostgreSQL should not take long.  If you import into a staging table (having `double`), you can do an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... double_column::numeric FROM staging_table` and it should be very fast.

Comment: Yes it is a way, even if creating a new table lengthens the code more then adding a phrase for each column the table has (in my case and because my first skils in PSQL don't let me to create a new table in less then 30 rows of code). Thank you @dezso